# Docker. How to get bash\ssh inside runned container (run -d)?

Tags: bash, ssh, vagrant, docker

I want to ssh or bash into runned docker container. Please, see example:

```
$ sudo docker run -d webserver
webserver is clean image from ubuntu:14.04
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE            COMMAND    CREATED STATUS  PORTS          NAMES
665b4a1e17b6  webserver:latest /bin/bash  ...     ...     22/tcp, 80/tcp loving_heisenberg 

now I want to get something like this (go into runned container):
$ sudo docker run -t -i webserver (or maybe 665b4a1e17b6 instead)
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Previously I used Vagrant so I want to get behavior similar to `vagrant ssh`. Please, could anyone help me?

Comment: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is docker `attach` command.

For information see: https://askubuntu.com/a/507009/159189

Answer (score 3):

After the release of [Docker version 1.3](http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/), the correct way to get a shell or other process on a running container is using the `docker exec` command. For example, you would run the following to get a shell on a running container:

`docker exec -it myContainer /bin/bash`

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec).